# How to get more information about the remote branches

Tags: git, github

Using `git`, if I make `git branch --all` I can see all remotes branches.

It will be possible to get more information about this `remote branches`,
for example the "creation date", "last edit date" and the "creation user" by command line?

Comment: `git branch --all -v` will also give you the latest commit hash and message

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter I think the OP is looking for commit metadata on remote branches.

Comment: +1 @c00kiemon5ter. anyway `git branch -all -v` not git `branch --all -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No. You need to fetch repository objects to view history information.

#### How Git Works

Git history is stored in commit objects, but branches are just pointers to commits. (This is a slight simplication, but true for our purposes.) In particular, a remote ref is just a pointer to the head of some branch; it doesn't contain any history to display.

Git need to retrieve the repository objects for that branch in order to calculate history at run-time. So, until you run `git fetch` for a given branch, there's nothing for Git to look at to give you that information.

Comment: Ofcourse you need to have an updated repo (ie you need to `git fetch` first). I took that for granted, good point bringing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Any command you use to get info for *local* branches, will also work for *remote* ones.

ie:

```
$ git checkout origin/foo
$ git log --oneline -5
$ git show upstream/dev
# etc
```